# No Wrapper Element when returning List

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS / JAXB and JPA to create an REST Webservice.

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<MyObject> getList() {
    List<MyObject> resultList = em.createNamedQuery(
            "MyObject.findAll").getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

returns

```
{
    "MYObject": [
        {
            "attribute": "value"
        },
        {
            "attribute": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

and for xml:

```
    <mYObject>
      <MObject>
        <attribute>value</attribute>
      </MyObject>
      <MyObject>
        <attribute>value</attribute>
      </MyObject>
    </mYObject>
```

How can I get rid of the wrapper element? OK, xml needs a root element (mYObject) but how can I rename it?
Is it possible for JSON two have a output like this:

```
   [
        {
            "attribute": "value"
        },
        {
            "attribute": "value"
        }
    ]
```

==> No Wrapper object, just the plain array with all the objects?

Comment: Web service on ... what? I.e. which container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stay with the default List-marshaling.

However, if you want to archive a custom marshaling and naming you have to  write you own [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [MessageBodyWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if I get you right. But I guess you want:

1. rename mYObject
2. get rid of MyObject

For question 1,

-- you could use @XmlRootElement(name="NOTmYObject") to override it as NOTmYObject.

For question 2,

-- if you want the data structure in your POJO be different from json in HTTP, JaxB doesn't assume this kind of flexibility. JaxB treat it, the data structure, strictly like a contract between service and client. Using xsd files to define this contract is more strait forward. Or if you really need that *flexibility*, you may want to take a look at *jackson* instead.

Comment: Thanks :)

1) Does not work, It renames the Tag of every Element "MYObject". But NOT the outer "wrapper-/ListTag" Element "mYObjects".

For 2): It's not that I want the POJO structure to be different - I return an ArrayList of Objects, so I expect an Array with objects. And not an object that contains an array of objects...

Comment: 1)There is no easy solution for specifying wrapper tag. Check [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/returning_xml_representation_of_list) for solution using '@Provider'. 2)This is how JaxRS treats List<T> marshalling, you can use '@Provider' to specifiy your own way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`@XmlValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) in `MyObject` to annotate the `attribute`.

Comment: I can't use the @XmlValue Annotation on a class.

Comment: `attribute` is a property of `MyObject` class, not a class